# Proof of commutativity for topological I-semigroups

Tags: topological-groups, semigroups

A topological semigroup on a closed interval I and order topology is called *I-semigroup* if 1 acts as an identity and 0 as an annihilator.

I've seen in several articles that such I-semigroups should be **commutative**. Where can I find a straightforward proof? (or, even better, can you suggest me a simple proof?)

Thank you!

Comment: What is an annihilator in the context of semigroups? Is it an element $x$ in the semigroup $S$ such that $s.x=x=x.s$ for all $s\in S$?

Comment: @DanielRust yes, $1\cdot a=a=a\cdot 1$ and $0\cdot a=0=a\cdot 0$ for all $a\in I$

Comment: This theorem is stated, for example, in _"Logical, Algebraic, Analytic and Probabilistic Aspects of Triangular Norms"_ pag.83 (GoogleBooks), but I like to see a proof (without bigger guns)

Comment: By 1 and 0 I assume you mean the maximum and minimum elements?

Comment: @HarryAltman Yes

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but it's pretty easy to show that the set of pairs which do not commute in $I\times I$ is open if you consider the preimage of the map $f\colon I\times I\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x\cdot y- y\cdot x$. Similarly, the center of the semigroup is closed. Also, for any point $b$ on the boundary of $I\times I$, we have $f(b)=0$ as well as any point in the diagonal $\Delta(I\times I)=\{(x,x)\mid x\in I\}$.

Comment: Hold on -- what's "-", and where did $\mathbb{R}$ come from?  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question and it should be clarified.  Did "closed interval" mean $[0,1]$, or did it just mean a totally ordered set with a maximum and minimum element?  Or something inbetween?

Comment: @HarryAltman I was assuming that $I$ was the unit interval with the usual Euclidean topology. In this case $x\cdot y$ and $y\cdot x$ are also elements of $I$ and so we can take their difference as real numbers. Their difference is zero if and only if $x$ and $y$ commute under the semigroup structure.

Comment: Yes, I get that's what you meant; the question addressed to you was rhetorical.  But I'm still uncertain what Ralph meant.